# Usage of は in two different phrases

Tags: grammar, particle-は, time

As far as I understand the は particle marks the theme of the sentence. Sometimes it happens to be the subject, sometimes not. Is there any difference between this two formulation of the same idea?

1. わたしはきのう何もしませんでした。
2. (わたしは)きのう何もしませんでした。
3. きのうは何もしませんでした。

As far as I understand in the first one *I* am the theme, while the third one has *yesterday* as its theme. The second one is just the first one with the subject omitted. 2. And 3. differ for the presence of は. Are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: Instead of topic idea, I like disambiguation term. The idea of topic is to make it clear about what we talk. For example, without context 何もしませんでした is weird, because we don't know how to interpret. Thus every sentence has new information (what we want to say) and old information (to provide to whom/what it relates). In Japanese there are 4 places for topic: explicit は, context (evident or previously mentioned), predicate, occurrence (only for one-time events, mostly actions). Meaning changes depending on location (we provide different context), so correct answer depends on situation itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentences are all grammatically correct, but as a response to a question like "What did you do yesterday?", the third sentence is the most natural. The second one sounds unnatural because it lacks a topic.

The first one is natural in casual conversations only when saying わたしは explicitly is natural, for example when asked like "I went on a picnic yesterday, how about *you*?" Otherwise, we usually just drop わたしは and choose きのう as the topic.